# I have installed OpenAPI 3 using springdoc, but the URL is strange. Can I change it to the expected value?

Tags: springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I have installed swagger-ui using the following artifacts in my Java project's pom file:

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.2</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-security</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.2</version>
   </dependency>
```

I can view the swagger ui for my RESTful endpoints when I go to this URL

```
http://localhost:8081/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/v3/api-docs/swagger-config
```

but not this link

```
http://localhost:8081/swagger-ui/index.html
```

Why is this?  How can I change it back to the expected URL?

Answer (score 16):

Firstly, the below dependency has nothing to do with the issue you are mentioning.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-security</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Now to answer your question.

The URL http://localhost:8081/swagger-ui/index.html comes from the Swagger-Core library upon which Springdoc is built and thus it will serve the default Petstore example. Though this page can be disabled using the below property in `application.properties` file.

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.disable-swagger-default-url=true
```

But that holds only for version v1.4.1 and above.

#### Why /v3/api-docs/swagger-config ?

Now in the URl http://localhost:8081/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/v3/api-docs/swagger-config the query parameter `configUrl` specifies from where to fetch the Springdoc's Swagger-specific configuration file.

Now if you actually hit the URL http://localhost:8081/v3/api-docs/swagger-config, you'll get a config file that's similar to the one below

```json
{
  "configUrl": "/v3/api-docs/swagger-config",
  "docExpansion": "none",
  "urls": [
    {
      "url": "/v3/api-docs/default",
      "name": "default"
    }
  ],
  "validatorUrl": ""
}
```

The `urls` object encompasses individual objects for each API-group. Each API group is shown in the Swagger-UI as shown below

[image: api-group]

Now, for each API group, these properties are used by Springdoc to render the Swagger-UI by fetching the OpenAPI specification file from the given `url` and the `name` is rendered as shown in the above image.

As for the `docExpansion` property, it's set to `none` as that setting was explicitly specified in my `application.properties`

#### Playing with Properties

- > As of Springdoc 1.6.0, the below property is blocked by default for security reasons. Please refer to the comment [here](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/1765#issuecomment-1200401890) for more info. Use `springdoc.swagger-ui.queryConfigEnabled=true` to enable it at own risk since 1.6.0.

  Use the below property if you want to override the URL from where Springdoc's Swagger configuration file is fetched. Essentially the new URL should return a config file that's similar to the one returned from /v3/api-docs/swagger-config. Defaults to `/v3/api-docs/swagger-config`

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.configUrl=/mySpringdocConfig
```

- Use the below property to override the URL where your Springdoc's Swagger-UI loads. Defaults to `/swagger-ui.html`, and that's why Swagger-UI is available at http://localhost:8081/swagger-ui.html

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/mySwagger-UIPath
```

#### Conclusion

- I don't think it's possible to get rid of the `?configUrl=/v3/api-docs/swagger-config` from the URL, as it'll always be available and point to the location from where Sprinfdoc's configuration file will be fetched, which if not available will lead to an error in fetching the configuration file and thus make the Swagger-UI useless. Also, it's something you'll not want to get rid of as it's being used by the framework itself.
- Refer [here](https://springdoc.org/#swagger-ui-properties) for a list of all the supported properties to customize the behavior of Springdoc.

Comment: Note that `configUrl` is not longer an option, though I think they went a bit too far in removing it: https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/1765

Comment: Thanks! Updated the answer to reflect the same.

Answer (score 6):

You need to access the swagger ui at `http://localhost:8081/swagger-ui.html` instead of `http://localhost:8081/swagger-ui/index.html` which loads the pet store default swagger. You can check the work around at

```
https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/43
```

The url `http://localhost:8081/swagger-ui.html` will always get redirected to  `http://localhost:8081/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/v3/api-docs/swagger-config`.

You can customize with the following in application.properties

```
springdoc.api-docs.path=/api-docs 
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui-custom.html
```

Now the url `http://localhost:8081/swagger-ui-custom.html` will get redirected to  `http://localhost:8081/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/api-docs/swagger-config`.

Answer (score 4):

Below configuration helped customising the paths:

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=docs/ui
springdoc.swagger-ui.url=/api/openapi.json
springdoc.swagger-ui.disable-swagger-default-url=true
```

/api is context path for application

In the browser, I can navigate to http://localhost:8080/docs/ui which further redirects to http://localhost:8080/docs/swagger-ui/index.html as the default behaviour (which seems to be unavoidable). However, configUrl is not present at the end of redirected url.

Dependency used:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I configured the above 3 properties exactly like you mention above but it didn't work for me. I get 404. What could be going wrong?

Comment: @AndyDufresne did you find any fix , im getting 404 for the same