# OpenAPI, contract-first with Springdoc and multiple specs

Tags: swagger-ui, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I am trying to port a Swagger UI from Springfox to Springdoc.
The Swagger UI is generated via Maven plugin

```
<groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
<artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
```

... from two different OpenAPI specifications, both implemented in the same Spring Boot application. We use two different specs for two different clients.
So far, my Swagger UI looked like [this with Springfox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDEnX.png). Note the drop-down list that allows to choose the spec to display.

Now, with Springdoc 1.6.6, the Swagger-UI looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/326Tv.png).
Note that:

- The default landing page is the sample Pet Store and none of my specifications, although I specified in my Spring Boot's application.yaml:

  ```
  springdoc:
    swagger-ui:
      disable-swagger-default-url: true
  ```
- No drop-down
- I have to manually enter my specification's name into the "Explore" text field in order to see its Swagger UI
- I tried addressing the missing drop-down by following [I have installed OpenAPI 3 using springdoc, but the URL is strange. Can I change it to the expected value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65820916/i-have-installed-openapi-3-using-springdoc-but-the-url-is-strange-can-i-change), which claims to display a drop-down, but to no avail.

My questions:

- How do I display the drop-down? Does Springdoc support it at all out-of-the-box?

  - Apparently, accessing http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html?urls.primaryName=Information makes the drop-down list of specs magically appear.
- How do I make sure that the default URL http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html lands on one of my specs, and not on the Pet Store?

Here is btw. my Bean configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerDocumentationConfig {

/**
 * Path of the OpenAPI package extracted out of a random class in that package
 */
private static final String INFORMATION_PACKAGE = InformationApi.class.getPackageName();
/**
 * Path of the OpenAPI package extracted out of a random class in that package
 */
private static final String OPERATIONS_PACKAGE = OperationsApi.class.getPackageName();

private GroupedOpenApi getBaseApiDoc(String groupName, String packagePath) {
    return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
        .group(groupName)
        .packagesToScan(packagePath)
        .build();
}

@Bean
public GroupedOpenApi getOperationsApiDoc() {
    return getBaseApiDoc("Operations", OPERATIONS_PACKAGE);
}

@Bean
public GroupedOpenApi getInfoApiDoc() {
    return getBaseApiDoc("Information", INFORMATION_PACKAGE);
}
@Bean
public OpenAPI springShopOpenAPI() {
    return new OpenAPI()
        .info(new Info().title("SpringShop API")
            .description("Spring shop sample application")
            .version("v0.0.1")
            .license(new License().name("Apache 2.0").url("http://springdoc.org")))
        .externalDocs(new ExternalDocumentation()
            .description("SpringShop Wiki Documentation")
            .url("https://springshop.wiki.github.org/docs"));
}}
```