# spring boot - springdoc open api: No api definiation provided error

Tags: java, spring-boot, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I need to document my **spring boot** application's rest apis with [SpringDoc OpenApi](https://springdoc.org/). So, I added this dependency in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.8</version>
</dependency>
```

And here is my config class:

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public GroupedOpenApi apis() {
        return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
            .group("my-application")
            .packagesToScan("com.myapp.base")
            .pathsToMatch("/**")
            .build();
    }
}
```

When I want to use swagger-ui in `/base-url/swagger-ui/index.html`, the result is as below image:

[image]

What's wrong in my configuration?

I use spring boot 2.6.6.

Note: I don't see any problem to load swagger resources in browser console(401, 404). Also I have disabled spring security in app, there is not any problem related to security or loading swagger resources.

Comment: are you able to get some content when you got to /base-url/v3/api-docs/my-application this is URL where your definition  should be generated based on your config?

Comment: Does the package named `com.myapp.base` supplied to `packagesToScan()`  actually exist in your application and contain at least one `@RestController` ?

Comment: @vzhemevko The `.../v3/api-docs/...` returns json object that contains valid controllers data.

Comment: @dekkard Yes, the package exists and I have a `@RestController` inside the package. Also `.../v3/api-docs` returns valid json value contains that controller data.

Comment: @hamed as a suggestion try to remove the bean and just add the following props to your application props 

springdoc.packagesToScan=com.myapp.base
springdoc.api-docs.path=/api/api-docs
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/api/swagger-ui

then go to /base-url/api/swagger-ui in browser

Answer (score 0):

You bean looks okay to me but you're probably not hitting the right endpoint for the Swagger-UI.

The URL `/base-url/swagger-ui/index.html` points to the Swagger-UI provided by the Swagger Core library and there's not a lot you can do about it.

Springdoc has a transitive dependency on Swagger Core and as such the page is available. But the URL at which Springdoc exposes it's Swagger-UI is `/base-url/swagger-ui.html`.

Refer to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65848200/9269177) for an explanation on why is it so and the ways to update it.