# Swagger authentication permitAll() not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

I created a `JWT` project with Java 17 and Spring Boot 3. I was trying to include Swagger UI in my application, but when i try to access the `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/`, he asks me the credentials to access it.

My code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;

    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                    .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**", "/v2/api-docs",
                            "/swagger-resources",
                            "/swagger-resources/**",
                            "/configuration/ui",
                            "/configuration/security",
                            "/swagger-ui.html",
                            "/webjars/**",
                            "/v3/api-docs/**",
                            "/swagger-ui/**", "/configuration/**", "/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
            .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());

    return http.build();

    }
}
```

My dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

I already tried to configure the WebConfigSecurity class with the necessary endpoints like it's explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48971992).
I also tried to refactor the method as i've seen on this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api)  and upgraded the springfox version from 2.9.2 to 3.0.0 with no results.

Comment: just try to access swagger to `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html` path

Comment: @AndreiLisa i just tried, but it doesn't work. Thank you very much.

Comment: `http://localhost:8080/api/swagger-ui/index.html` maybe it is the path to swagger ui ? just  try and tell me if it is

Comment: yet again, this is not working. Thank you for the effort.

Comment: I am going to check your code on my machine i will came with an answer on this question.

Comment: instead of `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/` try to access with next one path `http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/swagger-ui/index.html`

Comment: i am sure it will work, i am going to write an answer

Comment: I tried but still doesn't work.  Thank you anyway. At this point i think that the problem is Java 17.

Comment: can you try also disable the cors and retry, add something like this into  `securityFilterChain` `http.cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);`

Comment: Still have the same problem, but i noticed that also the other endpoints required the authentication

Comment: If you will comment the security chain filter, will it work ?

Comment: As i thought this time it's even worse. If i try to go to `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/` it re-directs me to the authentication page.

Comment: Remove `.httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());` it is the cause

Comment: AFAIK springfox wasn't compatible with Spring Boot 3.X.X. I don't know if that changed over the months. When I first upgraded to 3.X.X I had to remove springfox, and I added openapi. [Here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springdoc/springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui/2.2.0) it's maven dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem also thanks to @dauthDaert06's comment. I simply changed the dependency, following some tips on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65848200/22629324). SpringFox is not compatible with 3.0.0 and upper Spring Boot versions.